# Como puedo identificar si existe una función

Tags: php, html

Hola estoy tratando de acomodar lo de la url amigable pero quiero saber cómo puedo hacer para poder identificar si la función introducida existe.

Por ejemplo yo tengo esta url que identifica un sitio del software `http://localhost/bavproyecto/` pero cuando se le agrega una segunda url se entiende que se está llamando un apartado de la pagina `http://localhost/bavproyecto/ver_reporte` pero si se le agrega una tercera es una función `http://localhost/bavproyecto/ver_reporte/nombre_de_la_funcion`.

Pero en el caso que se ponga el tercer parámetro que vendría siendo una función y no exista arroja un error y quiero saber cómo puedo hacer que si no encuentra la función me de error 404.

Este apartado es donde contrala todo:

```
<?php
require_once 'controladores/errores.php';

class App
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null; //obteniendo URL por variable GET  isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url']: null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = explode('/', $url);

        if (empty($url[0])) {
            $ruta = 'controladores/main.php';
            require_once $ruta;
            $controller = new Main();
            $controller->loadModel('main');
            $controller->render();
            return false;
        }


        $ruta = 'controladores/' . $url[0] . '.php';

        if (file_exists($ruta)) {
            require_once $ruta;
            $controller = new $url[0];
            $controller->loadModel($url[0]);
            
            if (isset($url[1])) {
                $controller->{$url[1]}();
            }else{
                $controller->render();
            }
        } else {
            $controller = new Errores();
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí es donde se indica el segundo es una `función $controller->{$url[1]}();`

el error que da:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> Ver_reporte::fff() in C:\xampp\htdocs\bavproyecto\lib\app.php:30 Stack
> trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\bavproyecto\index.php(14):
> App->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bavproyecto\lib\app.php on line 30

Comment: Prueba con **method_exist**, algo como: ```if (method_exists($controller,$url[1])) {}```

Comment: @DBE Si me función gracias otra :)
Otra pregunta da el mismo error pero si uno deja el / al final sin poner nada por ejemplo `http://localhost/bavproyecto/ver_reporte/ `

Comment: El segundo error, se me ocurre usar **rtrim()**, pero vi que ya lo usas en tu código: ```$url = rtrim($url, '/');```

Comment: Unnn si pero ese error se da si se le pone manualmente

Comment: Aunque lo pongas manualmente te debería de limpiar las barras invertidas, yo uso un modelo MVC parecido y uso la línea de trim() y me funciona bien.

Comment: unn ps no se que estara dando problema hay

Comment: Prueba hacer un ```var_dump($url);``` después de ```$url = rtrim($url, '/');``` y así compruebas a ver si te está funcionando, también puedes depurar el código y vas mirando cada paso. ¿Con si lo pongo manual, me imagino te refieres en la misma barra de dirección del navegador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comprobar que exista tu método (función), PHP dispone de la función

> `method_exist()` — comprueba si existe un método de una clase.

*Ejemplo:*

```
if (method_exists($controller,$url[1])) {
   // Metodo existe
} else {
  // Error 404
}
```

Respecto a tu comentaría si dejo una barra invertida al final (**/**), con `rtrim()` debería de funcionar.

*Ejemplo:*

```
// URL recibido por GET 
$url = isset($_GET['url']) && is_string($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
// Eliminamos barras invertidas al inicio y final de la URL
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
// Separamos la URL
$url = explode('/', $url);
```

Te dejo un ejemplo parecido, pero donde también podrías pasar parámetros a tus métodos.

**Ejemplo completo**

```
<?php
// Incluir clase Errores
require_once 'controladores/errores.php';

class App
{
    function __construct(
        private mixed $url = [], 
        private mixed $controller = null, 
    )
    {
        // URL recibido por GET 
        $this->url = isset($_GET['url']) && is_string($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        // Eliminamos barras invertidas al inicio y final de la URL
        $this->url = rtrim($this->url, '/');
        // Separamos los parametros de la URL
        $this->url = explode('/', $this->url);

        // Si no existen parametros en la URL abrimos pagina por defecto (www.domain.com)
        if (empty($this->url[0])) {
            $ruta = 'controladores/main.php';
            require_once $ruta;
            $this->controller = (object) new Main();
            $this->controller->loadModel('main');
            $this->controller->render();
            return false;
        }

        // Ruta
        $ruta = "controladores/{$this->url[0]}.php";

        // Comprobar si existe y es leeible
        if (file_exists($ruta) && is_readable($ruta)) :
            require_once $ruta;
            $this->controller = (object) new $this->url[0];
            $this->controller->loadModel($this->url[0]);
            
            // Comprobamos si hay un metodo en la url
            if (array_key_exists(1,$this->url)) :
                // Comprobar que el metodo existe
                if (method_exists($this->controller,$this->url[1])) : 
                   
                    // PARTE OPCIONAL
                    //
                    // Tambien existe parametros para el metodo (Ej: http://localhost/bavproyecto/ver_reporte/funcion/carlo/1/etc)
                    if (array_key_exists(2,$this->url)) :

                        // Reset
                        $param = []
                        #recorremos parametros desde la posicion 2
                        for ($i=2; $i < count($this->url); $i++) {
                            array_push($param,$this->url[$i]);
                        }
                        // Llamamos al metodo + parametros
                        $this->controller->{$this->url[1]}($param);

                    // Solo existe metodo (tus funciones) 
                    else :
                        $this->controller->{$this->url[1]}();
                    endif;
                //Pagina de error / 404  
                else : 
                    $this->controller = new Errores();
                    $this->controller->render();  
                    return false;
                endif;               
                
            // Solo existe controlador
            else:
                $this->controller->render();
            endif;                
            
        // Pagina de error / 404
        else :
            $this->controller = new Errores();
            $this->controller->render();
        endif;
    }
}
```

La parte opcional de los parámetros, la puedes obtener de la siguiente forma en tus métodos (funciones):

```
public function nombrefuncion(array $param = [])
{
    var_dump($param);
}
```

Comment: Hola en parte me funciono y disculpa el abuso pero tú crees que me puedes compartir el sistema mvc tuyo para comparar

Comment: Hola, realmente lo tengo para un futuro curso, pero te podría crear un ejemplo funcional y así comparas, si quieres me das el correo electrónico, y en cuanto tengo tiempo te lo envió, ya que aquí no puedo publicarlo. ¿Qué parte te funciono y que parte te dio problemas?

Comment: A ok, ya no me da el error pero yo creo que el mvc que tengo está mal configurado. Cuando pongo el / me muestra el mismo sitio que corresponde  (‘www.pagina.com/sitio/’) pero me daña los css que en parte ya lo acomode pero cuando toco alguna ruta o funcionalidades como que se descontrola la direcciones porque no reconoce las configuraciones que hice.
La cosa que ese MVC yo lo fui creando como practica para actividades de la universidad.

Comment: Si el curso es por una plataforma como YouTube me apunto XD

Comment: Vale en cuanto tengo un poco de tiempo, te creo un ejemplo y te lo envió. Es una plataforma que creí como hobby, pero por falta de tiempo no tengo aun ningún curso XD. Si quieres borra el mensaje de tu correo, ya lo guardé. Un saludo amigo

Comment: dale amigo muchas gracias